# How to remove straight lines from multiple rotated arc on canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to create [Star Trail](https://www.google.com/search?q=star%20trail) on canvas.

The idea to create it, i have to draw multiple images that increment size, and some calculation for the next image position. Store multiple image in array. Choose the image randomly each draw and draw it with different angle each image.

I made it.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas'),ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
var starsimage=['https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-prwJzDDwQRU/XTjNfQhQnDI/AAAAAAAACBo/wpbhqkfc-9wQQeg95O6poFbFyu77q4vdACLcBGAs/s1600/CircleWhite100.png','https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-lm4F2UOMCdE/XTjNghXjrOI/AAAAAAAACB0/L6pya6HQk0cU5R5RP9Wo_-Bm_UhO_qCawCLcBGAs/s1600/CircleWhite75.png','https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-7ennrlohEo0/XTjNfoji8KI/AAAAAAAACBw/G0SQhFEZ0IMMf2z3g_Mvbon97BMktSw-QCLcBGAs/s1600/CircleWhite50.png','https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-I7aeA-F4OWY/XTjNfiO-rxI/AAAAAAAACBs/lKYC-SmaWSQWc0PoPVdgCHeyDUPdoJd7gCLcBGAs/s1600/CircleWhite25.png','https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-V2Ak6YU2XNA/XTjNh7iIwZI/AAAAAAAACCA/tNo5Ho6iC4gndoftPJfSCInGqgyfcd6nQCLcBGAs/s1600/TrailBlue100.png','https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ylpi3AZvces/XTjNi7uy1kI/AAAAAAAACCM/uWZ7_zYRXXQN4q3QRSngCFeT5RoEeG4xgCLcBGAs/s1600/TrailBlue75.png','https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-NoPiS9k0o0U/XTjNivmKVjI/AAAAAAAACCI/gZzDMn9zomMWrQc2hhKfNB9JK0ruh2wyQCLcBGAs/s1600/TrailBlue50.png','https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-KYkWDwtmS7A/XTjNiSE8Y_I/AAAAAAAACCE/jDyTIbJqBBs3FP1tyGFICjShyx_GCCy0gCLcBGAs/s1600/TrailBlue25.png'];
var stars=new Array();var starsloaded=0;
var xpos=0,ypos=0,w=25,h=25,ix=0,xa=25,ya=25,rot=0,ang=0;

for(var i=0;i<starsimage.length;i++){//load images
 stars[i]=new Image();stars[i].src=starsimage[i];
 stars[i].onload=function(){starsloaded++;if(starsloaded==starsimage.length){
  draw();
 }}
}

function minmaxdraw(min,max){return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min}
function randomindeximage(l){return Math.floor(Math.random()*l)}

function draw(){
xpos=canvas.width/2;ypos=canvas.height/2;
for(var i=0;i<500;i++){//500 images
  xy=minmaxdraw(2,4);//gap randomly
  ix=randomindeximage(starsimage.length);
  w+=xy;h+=xy;ang=minmaxdraw(0,359);
  if(i>0){xa=w-xa;ya=h-ya;xpos=xpos-xa/2;ypos=ypos-ya/2;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(xpos+w/2,ypos+h/2);
    rot=ang*Math.PI/180;ctx.rotate(rot);
    ctx.drawImage(stars[ix],-w/2,-h/2,w,h);
    ctx.restore();
    xa=w;ya=h;
  }
  else{ctx.drawImage(stars[ix],xpos,ypos,w,h)}
}
}
```

```css
body{margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;background:#101010;height:580px;width:100%}
#canvas{z-index:2;background-color:transparent;position:absolute;width:100vw;left:50%;top:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%)}
body:before{content:'';z-index:1;position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0;background:linear-gradient(15deg, #1458ac, #000);}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="580"></canvas>
```

But. the quality is bad. Because the image size is static, blurry if the increment width is larger than actually image size, and the small stars is barely visible

I think, it's better to create it with multiple arc.
The idea is same, i have to draw multiple arc. But, i'm dummy, i made with two canvas, different angle each canvas. (It's actually same with my work before, but at the time, i use 1 image that have cutted circle). Because if i made it only on one canvas, the straight line appears. So, i draw multiple arc in each canvas. It works, and no straight line appears. (It's still basic arc)

```js
var canvas1=document.getElementById('canvas1'),ctx=canvas1.getContext('2d'),canvas2=document.getElementById('canvas2'),ctx2=canvas2.getContext('2d');var xy=0;var angle=new Array();

function minmaxdraw(min,max){return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min}
function randomindeximage(l){return Math.floor(Math.random()*l)}

function draw1(){
var xpos=canvas1.width/2;var ypos=canvas1.height/2;var r=15,ang=0;
ctx.beginPath();
for(var i=0;i<55;i++){
  r+=minmaxdraw(4,9);
  ctx.moveTo(xpos + r, ypos);
  ctx.arc(xpos, ypos, r, 0, 1.5*Math.PI,true);
}ctx.stroke();
}
function draw2(){
var xpos=canvas2.width/2;var ypos=canvas2.height/2;var r=15;
ctx2.beginPath();
for(var t=0;t<55;t++){
  r+=minmaxdraw(4,9);
  ctx2.moveTo(xpos, ypos + r);
  ctx2.arc(xpos, ypos, r, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI);
}ctx2.stroke();
}

draw1();draw2();
```

```css
body{margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;height:480px;width:100%}
.canvas{background-color:transparent;position:absolute;width:100vw;left:50%;top:50%;margin:-50% 0 0 -50%}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas1' class='canvas' width='640' height='480'></canvas>
<canvas id='canvas2' class='canvas' width='640' height='480'></canvas>
```

It's not rotated yet.
So, if i want make circle trail, i have to rotate each arc randomly like i did before with image, but the problem is here. The straight lines come wickedly.

```js
var canvas1=document.getElementById('canvas1'),ctx=canvas1.getContext('2d'),canvas2=document.getElementById('canvas2'),ctx2=canvas2.getContext('2d');var xy=0;var angle=new Array();

function minmaxdraw(min,max){return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min}
function randomindeximage(l){return Math.floor(Math.random()*l)}

function draw1(){
var xpos=canvas1.width/2;var ypos=canvas1.height/2;
var r=15,ang=0,dx=0,dy=0;
ctx.beginPath();
for(var i=0;i<55;i++){//200 images
  ang=minmaxdraw(0,359);
  dx=minmaxdraw(0,canvas1.width),dy=minmaxdraw(0,canvas1.height);
  r+=minmaxdraw(3,7);
  ang=Math.atan2(dx-xpos,dy-ypos);angle[i]=ang;
  ctx.moveTo(xpos, ypos);
  ctx.arc(xpos, ypos, r, ang + 0 * Math.PI, ang + Math.PI * 1.5,true);
}ctx.stroke();
}
function draw2(){
var xpos=canvas2.width/2;var ypos=canvas2.height/2;var r=15;
ctx2.beginPath();
for(var t=0;t<55;t++){
  r+=minmaxdraw(3,7);
  ctx2.moveTo(xpos, ypos + r);
  ctx2.arc(xpos, ypos, r, angle[t] + Math.PI / 2, angle[t] + Math.PI);
}ctx2.stroke();
}
draw1();draw2();
```

```css
body{margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;height:480px;width:100%}
.canvas{background-color:transparent;position:absolute;width:100vw;left:50%;top:50%;margin:-50% 0 0 -50%}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas1' class='canvas' width='640' height='480'></canvas>
<canvas id='canvas2' class='canvas' width='640' height='480'></canvas>
```

Is there any solution to remove that straight lines?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you have the calls to `moveTo` and maybe I just didn't understand the question but I just moved `beginPath` and `stroke` inside the loops.

```js
var canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas1'),
  ctx = canvas1.getContext('2d'),
  canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2'),
  ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
var xy = 0;
var angle = new Array();

function minmaxdraw(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
}

function randomindeximage(l) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * l)
}

function draw1() {
  var xpos = canvas1.width / 2;
  var ypos = canvas1.height / 2;
  var r = 15,
    ang = 0,
    dx = 0,
    dy = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 55; i++) { //200 images
    ang = minmaxdraw(0, 359);
    dx = minmaxdraw(0, canvas1.width), dy = minmaxdraw(0, canvas1.height);
    r += minmaxdraw(3, 7);
    ang = Math.atan2(dx - xpos, dy - ypos);
    angle[i] = ang;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(xpos, ypos, r, ang + 0 * Math.PI, ang + Math.PI * 1.5, true);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function draw2() {
  var xpos = canvas2.width / 2;
  var ypos = canvas2.height / 2;
  var r = 15;
  for (var t = 0; t < 55; t++) {
    r += minmaxdraw(3, 7);
    ctx2.beginPath();
    ctx2.arc(xpos, ypos, r, angle[t] + Math.PI / 2, angle[t] + Math.PI);
    ctx2.stroke();
  }
}
draw1();
draw2();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 550px;
  width: 100%
}

.canvas {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -50% 0 0 -50%
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas1' class='canvas' width='640' height='480'></canvas>
<canvas id='canvas2' class='canvas' width='640' height='480'></canvas>
```

Also I don't understand why you have 2 canvases. It works fine with just one

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var xy = 0;
var angle = new Array();

function minmaxdraw(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
}

function randomindeximage(l) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * l)
}

function draw1() {
  var xpos = canvas.width / 2;
  var ypos = canvas.height / 2;
  var r = 15,
    ang = 0,
    dx = 0,
    dy = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 55; i++) { //200 images
    ang = minmaxdraw(0, 359);
    dx = minmaxdraw(0, canvas.width), dy = minmaxdraw(0, canvas.height);
    r += minmaxdraw(3, 7);
    ang = Math.atan2(dx - xpos, dy - ypos);
    angle[i] = ang;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(xpos, ypos, r, ang + 0 * Math.PI, ang + Math.PI * 1.5, true);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function draw2() {
  var xpos = canvas.width / 2;
  var ypos = canvas.height / 2;
  var r = 15;
  for (var t = 0; t < 55; t++) {
    r += minmaxdraw(3, 7);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(xpos, ypos, r, angle[t] + Math.PI / 2, angle[t] + Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
draw1();
draw2();
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' class='canvas' width='640' height='480'></canvas>
```

The reason you got lines before is all `arc` does is add points.

`arc` is effectively this

```
// pseudo code
function arc(x, y, radius, start, end) {
  const numSegments = 100; // no idea what number real arc uses here
  for (let i = 0; i < numSegments; ++i) {
    const angle = start + (end - start) * i / numSegments;
    ctx.lineTo(Math.cos(angle) * radius, Math.sin(angle) * radius);
  }
}
```

As you can see the code above just adds the points around the arc. So if you do a

```
ctx.moveTo(x, y);
ctx.arc(x, y, ...);
```

you're adding a point in the center of the arc and then more points to the edge. That's why you're getting a line from the centers to the edge of each arc.

If you wanted to leave the code the same as you had it and just stroke all the arcs at once then you'd need to change the `moveTo` to move to the edge of the arc instead of the center.

```
ctx.moveTo(x + Math.cos(start) * radius, y + Math.sin(start) * radius);
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, start, ...);
```

Comment: Thank you. That straight lines has removed now.
I'm so dummy, i remember that .moveTo() i made is help me to remove the straight lines from arc that not rotated yet.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you again. I made 2 canvas, because i don't know yet how to remove that straight lines. It's appear when i just draw it on 1 canvas.
I'm too 'step by step' person. First i made a full circle with some gap like this in 1 canvas. So i need the moveTo() to remove the straight line from /questions/23668459/issue-on-drawing-multiple-circles-on-html5-canvas. And i make 2 canvas before because mirror concept like i made this before with image. It's like 2 arc opposite each other in 1 circle path. I don't know yet, i need that or just draw that in 1 canvas for now. But, thank you again.